# Prevent onclick within another onclick of the same control

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, onclick

I have a button with an onclick event

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btn_Save_Click"/>
```

I have a second onclick event for this button as it can be seen in below.

```
((Button)btn).Click += new EventHandler(SaveClicked);
```

I debugged and saw that the first one occurs before the second one,

I want to cancel the second onclick from the first one.

**Why do I need 2 click events:**
I have a webcontrol (BulkEditGridView), which takes a Button control as parameter, and this control saves whole rows. Second click event acts as save whole table. Now I added some fields to my webcontrol and I want to prevent saving when button is clicked. Since I can not modify the webcontrols eventhandler (second click event), I added the first onclick event. What I am tring to do is, prevent saving of the gridview, if one of the fields (ex: a textbox field) is empty, which can be done by prevent the default click event.

Comment: is it necessary to write this event handler, which is causing Onclick for another button in `btn_Save_Click`..you can either remove this line or change order of your code's line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session variable can be used .

Answer (score 2):

Just remove second event handler from button click event.

```
((Button)btn).Click -= new EventHandler(SaveClicked);
```

but when you not required second event handler, why are you adding that?

You can remove event handler by reflection also, you can try this code, but not tested.

```
BindingFlags AllBindings = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

List<FieldInfo> lst = new List<FieldInfo>();

foreach (EventInfo ei in btn.GetType().GetEvents(AllBindings))
{
    Type dt = ei.DeclaringType;
    FieldInfo fi = dt.GetField(ei.Name, AllBindings);
    if (fi != null)
        lst.Add(fi);
}

foreach (FieldInfo fi in lst)
{
    EventInfo ei = btn.GetType().GetEvent(fi.Name, AllBindings);
    if (ei != null)
    {
        object val = fi.GetValue(btn);
        Delegate mdel = (val as Delegate);
        if (mdel != null)
        {
            foreach (Delegate del in mdel.GetInvocationList())
                ei.RemoveEventHandler(btn, del);
        }
    }
}
```

It will remove all event handler. for more info you can check this link  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection

Comment: they are not in the same class, so "SaveClicked" can not be seen from the first onclick.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether i have understood your query correctly.

Remove first method using -=
and then add your second method and then again add first method.

So, you will get first executed your second method.

Again, not sure